# Filter Data in MS SQL

Tags: json, sql-server, database, t-sql, sql-server-2016

Hello Guys I  have a big number of data in the database so I need a method to filter sql data and just a specific data from it.

e.g: I want to get name and text from this code

```
INSERT INTO `Employers` VALUES 
('rgthtr5','9123123','{"name":"Mohamed","text":"employer","bla":"
bla","bla":"bla"})
```

Comment: What's your dbms

Comment: my database is sqlite

Comment: i work also on ms sql server

Comment: i edited my post if you want to recheck it

Comment: so? sqlite or mssqlserver?

Comment: is this a JSON? SQL Server 2016 has a JSON data type that can do what you want.

Comment: i work on ms sql server 2016. I want to filter this json data to just get the name and text

Comment: I don't have 2016 where I am so I cannot test JSON queries. Please see this article https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/json-support-in-sql-server-2016/ from which you can copy queries that include a where clause.

Comment: man just give me any solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get values from json with `JSON_VALUE`:

```
declare @tmp table ([code] varchar(10), [ncode] varchar(10), [json] varchar(max))

INSERT INTO @tmp VALUES 
 ('rgthtr5', '9123123', '{"name":"Mohamed1","text":"employer1","bla":"bla","bla":"bla"})')
,('rgthtr6', '9123124', '{"name":"Mohamed2","text":"employer2","bla":"bla","bla":"bla"})')
,('rgthtr7', '9123125', '{"name":"Mohamed3","text":"employer3","bla":"bla","bla":"bla"})')

select 
    [code], 
    [ncode], 
    JSON_VALUE([json], '$.name') as [name], 
    JSON_VALUE([json], '$.text') as [text]
from @tmp
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: can i  use it in SQLite ?

Comment: @Mohamed This works in SQL Server. Don't know about SQLite since your question is tagged with SQL Server.